# Vim: Can't exit Visual Mode using jk (Arpeggio Chord)

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I use Arpeggio to map <kbd>jk</kbd> to <kbd>ESC</kbd>
So when I press <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> simultaneously I can exit to normal mode very quickly.

I found this trick from 
[Arpeggio plugin page](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2425)

This is what I put in .vimrc

```
Arpeggio inoremap jk <ESC>
```

Exiting from Insert mode works perfectly, But I can not exit from Visual Mode.
It would be nice if I can exit both mode so I can stick with this key, It save my time a lot.

Any idea?

Edited:
I can not exit Insert(paste) mode too

```
:set paste
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
inoremap
```

is for insert mode mappings, use

```
xnoremap
```

for visual mode.

Assuming that plugin is able to handle visual mode mappings, duplicating that line in your ~/.vimrc and replacing the i with a x should be enough.

Comment: This works well, Thank you. But now I can't exit Insert(paste) mode, Please help.

Comment: Don't use paste mode: Vim can perfectly paste without that crap. From `:help 'paste'`: "mapping in Insert mode and Command-line mode is disabled" so your `inoremap` won't work. Don't use paste mode.

Comment: @romainl I know this is old but just my 2¢: Setting `xnoremap jk <Esc>` is not optimal, because those keys are also used to go up/down a line. This means, whenever you are in visual mode and want to go down one line (pressing `j`) vim will wait/hang/stutter because it does not know if you want to exit (`jk`) visual mode or just go down a line (`j`).

Answer (score 0):

I **need** paste mode if I want to paste big files into a buffer, while using all of my plugins, syntax highlighting etc. Without paste mode this would take forever or even hang, depending on the filesize...

Therefore I have set a "paste toggle on F3" keybinding:

```
set pastetoggle=<f3>
```

So whenever I press F3 it will toggle paste mode on/off.

Additionally, to exit paste mode whenever I leave insert mode I have this auto-command in vimrc:

```
autocmd InsertLeave * set nopaste
```

So after I have pasted something (being in insert mode afterwards) I can press `Ctrl-o` or `ESC` and paste mode is turned off automatically.